# Differential of a function defined on matrices $F(M)=MJM^T$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I am trying to find the differential of the function

$$F:M=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix}\mapsto MJM^T$$
where $J=\begin{pmatrix}0 & I \\ -I & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $A, B, C, D, 0, I$ are $n\times n$ matrices.

I got that $F(M)=\begin{pmatrix}
  -BA+AB & -BC+AD \\
  -DA+CB & -DC+CD
  \end{pmatrix}$, but I have no idea how to differentiate the function with respect to matrices.

Comment: Have you tried the matrix cookbook? https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf (Page 8)

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf might also help.

Comment: @user1551 It should be $MJM^T$. Fixed.

Comment: @  user317301 , I got that you are wrong: $MJM^T=\begin{pmatrix}-BA^T+AB^T&-BC^T+AD^T\\-DA^T+CB^T&-DC^T+CD^T\end{pmatrix}$.